# Multiplexed hotspot in Android

Tags: android, api, wifi, android-wifi

Is it possible to write an app in Android using the wifi API which will act like a hotspot (so granting network access to wifi clients) while still allowing the local wifi device to connect to another wifi network ?

The one I've tested are disabling local Wifi connection in order to create a hotspot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I post here after a few months so people that would like to implement this on an Android device might be helped.

There is a way to have one wireless chip working in hybrid mode, with both *station mode* (STA) and *access point mode* (AP) enabled.

To do this, I replaced the wireless driver of my chip with a `multi-role` wireless driver. Luckily enough, my chip was supporting this mode, it is however not the case for every wireless chips. My chip being a TI based chip *(wl1271)*, multi role was supported, though it was not available with the previous driver.

Once I got this new driver, I had to recompile it along with my kernel in order to have the `.ko` of the wireless driver and the related `mac80211` and `cfg80211` modules (providing the APIs needed by the new driver) generated. The last step was to upgrade `wpa_supplicant` and `hostapd` with a custom patched version provided by TI.

Again, for people interested in `wl1271` *only* here are the corresponding drivers/tools I used and reported working on *Android 4.0.4 ICS* :

> https://github.com/TI-OpenLink/hostap/tree/ol_R5.SP3.01
>
> https://github.com/TI-OpenLink/iw/tree/ol_R5.SP3.01
>
> https://github.com/TI-OpenLink/ti-utils/tree/ol_R5.SP3.01
>
> https://github.com/TI-OpenLink/wl12xx_target_scripts/tree/ol_R5.SP3.01/sta
>
> https://github.com/TI-OpenLink/compat/tree/ol_R5.SP3.01/
>
> https://github.com/TI-OpenLink/compat-wireless/tree/ol_R5.SP3.01/

If there is a multi role driver for your wireless chip, it might be worth it finding out what version or patches of wpa_supplicant and hostapd you shall use, and compile/try them.

At the end of the process, I had access to two network interfaces (wlan0 and wlan1), and could launch wpa_supplicant on wlan0 and hostapd on wlan1.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called [WDS (Wireless Distribution System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system). I think that this functionality is not implemented in Android wifi API. It is used in wireless APs to enable a wireless link upstream.

Comment: It refers indeed to what I wanted. Nevertheless, WDS seems to wrap a lot of concepts and protocols. I just wanted some simple advise on how to do that w/o having a whole AP sharing system. Some advise on how to do that with the Android API (seems not implemented) or electronically (maybe using a second wifi device) -> and how to that in Android w/o changing the kernel :).

Comment: @HQarroum My understanding (and I am not an expert on this) is that you would need at least a WDS capable AP and a compatible implementation of WDS in Android. I think that this is not currently implemented in Android, and thus would require some fairly low-level coding...

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will investigate on this more deeply :)