# Android JellyBean and P2P support

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct

I am analysing Android JellyBean 4.3 source code.I could find the varialbe p2p_supported in HAL layer for Wi-Fi Direct support. In the below code snippet from wifi_ath.c

int wifi_start_supplicant(int p2p_supported)
{

```
if (p2p_supported) 
  {
    strcpy(supplicant_name, P2P_SUPPLICANT_NAME);
    strcpy(supplicant_prop_name, P2P_PROP_NAME);  // for P2P support
    .......................
   }
    else {
    strcpy(supplicant_name, SUPPLICANT_NAME);
    strcpy(supplicant_prop_name, SUPP_PROP_NAME); //for station support
       }
```

The values of  the macros are:

```
P2P_SUPPLICANT_NAME = p2p_supplicant ,P2P_PROP_NAME= init.svc.p2p_supplicant
SUPPLICANT_NAME=wpa_supplicant ,SUPP_PROP_NAME=init.svc.wpa_supplicant
```

Even while connecting in station mode the if part is getting executed and I could not make the WiFi up. Where in the code exactly p2p_supported variable is enabled and disabled so that both the P2P and Wi-Fi works smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

From Jelly Bean(4.1) you only need to turn WiFi on to use WiFi Direct functionality, though using both together depends upon whether your chip supports it.(For that see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540884/can-wifi-direct-and-wifi-station-work-simultaneously) SO question)