# Can i send data through wifi while on another connection

Tags: wifi

Wanted to know if I can send data through my phone wifi while I am already on another wifi connection? To explain better, let us say I am using my phone to access the Internet. Now I would like to send an instruction through my phone to a wifi module. Can I send this instruction while I am still connected to my wifi router?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can WIFI direct and WIFI station work simultaneously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540884/can-wifi-direct-and-wifi-station-work-simultaneously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to send data over the wifi you need to be connected to the same network . For example if you use wifi direct to transfer data between 2 devices then these **devices will be connected to each other over the wifi interface** and **hence you cannot be connected to another wifi router at the same time** .To be able to send the instruction over wifi you will have to connect to the other device and **break your connection with the existing router.**

However to achieve this you can **stay connected to your router and transfer the data using bluetooth** .You can **connect to the other device using bluetooth and stay connected to your wifi simultaneously**