# Custom Android with Two Wi-Fi Adapters

Tags: android, customization, android-wifi, hal

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540884/can-wifi-direct-and-wifi-station-work-simultaneously) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499456/multiplexed-hotspot-in-android) threads, I understood that if You only have one WiFi adapter, you can either connect to a hotspot or host one, not do both at the same time unless your driver and chipset support it.

In my case, I have a custom hardware with ***Two separate Wif-Fi adapter***. Android M will be the OS running on it. My question is

1. Is it possible to control and configure those two Wi-Fi devices independently from android application layer?
2. What will be the changes that I should implement in Wi-Fi HAL module to make this possible?
3. In order to connect to wifi on a single adapter device we use WifiManager,  But how can it be used for connecting both adapters?

What we trying to achieve in here is to use one wifi adapter to act as an access point (tethering) and the other adapter to connect to a different network. These connections management should be available from the application layer so that user can connect and disconnect wifi to his needs.