# Check if WiFi and WiFi Direct can work simultaneously

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct

Not all Android devices support simultaneous WiFi and WiFi-Direct connection - eg, Samsung S3, RedMi, OnePlus, Nexus, allows for both, but most Motorola phones I've tested on (Moto E1, E2, E3) show a popup asking user to switch off WiFi when I call `wifiP2pManager.connect()`.

Is there a way to check if the Android device supports simultaneous connection? I'd like to not allow Android devices that do not support simultaneous connections to be able to use my app.

Edit :
I've had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499456/multiplexed-hotspot-in-android) and from that I understand Moto phones may not have the wireless drivers for `multi-role`. But this still doesn't hint at *how* to figure out if the device supports multi-role or not.